# Proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality using the principle of mathematical induction

Tags: inequality

I've seen several proofs for the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but none with the principle of mathematical induction and that's the easiest kind of proof.

Comment: Induction ? Cauchy-Schwarz ? What do you mean ?

Comment: Induction only makes sense if you are trying to prove something for every value of an integer $n$. This isn't the cause in Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 2):

Inductive case:

Suppose the inequality holds when $n=k$, i.e.
\begin{align}
a_1b_1+\ldots + a_kb_k \leq \sqrt{a_1^2+\ldots +a_k^2}\sqrt{b_1^2+\ldots+b_k^2}. 
\end{align}
Consider the case $n=k+1$. Observe
\begin{align}
a_1b_1+\ldots + a_kb_k+a_{k+1}b_{k+1} \leq \sqrt{a_1^2+\ldots +a_k^2}\sqrt{b_1^2+\ldots+b_k^2}+a_{k+1}b_{k+1}
\leq \sqrt{a_1^2+\ldots +a_k^2+a_{k+1}^2}\sqrt{b_1^2+\ldots+b_k^2+b_{k+1}^2}
\end{align}
where the last inequality is the Cauchy-Schwarz for the case $n=2$.